# How do you iterate objects in array?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm doing a quiz with only jquery and I need to get data from the JSON API through ajax, the data from the JSON API is randomly selected how do I get access properties of the objects?

I did it in this way but is there any other way I can do it instead of writing every single question down.

I'm new to Jquery:) please help

```
    $("p:eq(0)").text(data.results[0].question);
    $("p:eq(1)").text(data.results[1].question);
    $("p:eq(2)").text(data.results[2].question);
    $("p:eq(3)").text(data.results[3].question);
    $("p:eq(4)").text(data.results[4].question);
    $("p:eq(5)").text(data.results[5].question);
```

Comment: This isn't specific to jQuery; it's just JavaScript. Maybe a JS tutorial would be a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Or just do `$('p').each(function(i){$(this).text(data.results[i].question)})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
    $("p:eq(" + i + ")").text(data.results[i].question);
}
```

Comment: what does the  $("p:eq(" + i + ")") do ? i dont understand that part

Comment: When `i == 0` in the loop, `$("p:eq(" + i + ")")` will evaluate to `$("p:eq(0)")`. When `i == 1`, it will evaluate to `$("p:eq(1)")`, etc.